# Prestashop add or edit product the Save buttons are loading in continuously

Tags: javascript, php, prestashop

I know this question was asked many time, how ever I tried all possible fix but nothing worked for me.

Everything was working great, I didn't do any updates. My Prestashop virsion is 1.6.1.16

But yesterday, after I finished making my theme, I decided to start adding new products, and this issue stopped me. When I I open the console this error was shown:

```
products.js:170 Uncaught TypeError: this.current_request.complete is not a function
    at ProductTabsManager.displayBulk (products.js:170)
    at index.php?controller=AdminProducts&id_product=8&updateproduct&token=42575a03759c92767d819a1e5bed02af:1121
    at dispatch (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3)
    at q.handle (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3)
ProductTabsManager.displayBulk @ products.js:170
(anonymous) @ index.php?controller=AdminProducts&id_product=8&updateproduct&token=42575a03759c92767d819a1e5bed02af:1121
dispatch @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3
```

on products.js at line 170:

```
if (this.current_request !== undefined)
        {
            this.current_request.complete(function(request, status) {
                var wrong_statuses = new Array('abort', 'error', 'timeout');
                var wrong_status_code = new Array(400, 401, 403, 404, 405, 406, 408, 410, 413, 429, 499, 500, 502, 503, 504);

                if ((in_array(status, wrong_statuses) || in_array(request.status, wrong_status_code)) && !self.page_reloading) {
                    var current_tab = '';
                    if (request.responseText !== 'undefined' && request.responseText && request.responseText.length) {
                        current_tab = $(request.responseText).filter('.product-tab').attr('id').replace('product-', '');
                    }

                    jAlert((current_tab ? 'Tab : ' + current_tab : '') + ' (' + (request.status ? request.status + ' ' : '' ) + request.statusText + ')\n' + reload_tab_description, reload_tab_title);
                    self.page_reloading = true;
                    self.has_error_loading_tabs = true;
                    clearTimeout(tabs_running_timeout);
                    return false;
                }
                else if (!self.has_error_loading_tabs && (self.stack_done.length === self.tabs_to_preload.length)) {
                        $('[name="submitAddproductAndStay"]').each(function() {
                            $(this).prop('disabled', false).find('i').removeClass('process-icon-loading').addClass('process-icon-save');
                        });
                        $('[name="submitAddproduct"]').each(function() {
                            $(this).prop('disabled', false).find('i').removeClass('process-icon-loading').addClass('process-icon-save');
                        });
                        this.allow_hide_other_languages = true;
                        clearTimeout(tabs_running_timeout);
                        return false;
                    }
                return true;
            });
        }
```

Comment: Hi AndrewS I can see it's an old question, but did you resolve this issue?

Comment: same problem here, anyone?